# How to keep the width fixed on each item in a flex container?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to keep the width fixed in each item in a flex container by arranging only three items per row?

I want to arrange three items per row but keep the width unchanged and aligned to the center.

```css
* {background:#C8c8c8;}


.row {
display:flex; 
width:100%; gap:1rem; 
justify-content:center; 
align-items:center; 
flex-wrap:wrap; 
}

.item {width:45px; height:45px; background: gray;
flex:0 0 25%;
}

.a2 {background: blue;}
.a3 {background: orange;}
.a4 {background: green;}
.a5 {background: red;}
.a6 {background: brown;}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="item a1"></div>
<div class="item a2"></div>
<div class="item a3"></div>
<div class="item a4"></div>
<div class="item a5"></div>
<div class="item a6"></div>

  
  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not possible using flex with your current HTML structure.
But it's easily achievable using grid.

```css
* {
  background: #C8c8c8;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  place-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  background: gray;
}


.a2 {
  background: blue;
}

.a3 {
  background: orange;
}

.a4 {
  background: green;
}

.a5 {
  background: red;
}

.a6 {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item a1"></div>
    <div class="item a2"></div>
    <div class="item a3"></div>
    <div class="item a4"></div>
    <div class="item a5"></div>
    <div class="item a6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```